# I am getting different errors dependent on the compiler I am using. However, I used valgrind and I was given a __pthread_tpp_change_priority error

Tags: c, debugging, operating-system, synchronization, pthreads

I am attempting to learn how to create a multi-threaded program for a school project. I am having issues trying to debug my project. It might look like a hot pile of garbage, so I apologize in advance. I'm not too strong in my programming skills, which is the reason why I am having difficulty finding problems. Any direction is appreciated!

lunch.c:

```
#include "mytime.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define MAX 50

int ticketCounter = 1;
int maxCustomer, maxServer, nowServing, currServer;
sem_t empty, full; // for buffer
sem_t servers;
pthread_mutex_t getTicketLock, waitTurnLock, waitCustomerLock, buffLock;

typedef struct LUNCH {
    long int TID;
    int ticketNum;
    int numServers;
    unsigned int takeALooksy;
    sem_t ready;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} lunch;

lunch *orderList;
int listCount = 0, producer = 0, consumer = 0;

void lunch_init();
int lunch_get_ticket(lunch *cust);
void lunch_wait_turn(lunch *cust);
void lunch_wait_customer(lunch *cust); // server waits for a cust to appear
void ordersUp(lunch cust); // add customer to orderList
void consume();
void show_serving(int num);
void *customer(void *threadId);
void *server(void *threadId);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <total number of servers> <total number of customers>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    srand(time(NULL)); // for random number seed
    maxServer = atoi(argv[1]);
    maxCustomer = atoi(argv[2]);
    currServer = maxServer;

    lunch_init();
    lunch Lunch;
    pthread_t custThreads[maxCustomer], serverThreads[maxServer];

    for (int i = 0; i < maxCustomer; i++) {
        if ((pthread_create(&(custThreads[i]), NULL, customer, &Lunch)) != 0) {
            perror("customer pthread_create() error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxServer; i++) {
        if ((pthread_create(&(serverThreads[i]), NULL, server, &Lunch)) != 0) {
            perror("server pthread_create() error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxCustomer; i++) {
        pthread_join(custThreads[i], NULL);
    }    

    for (int i = 0; i < maxServer; i++) {
        pthread_cancel(serverThreads[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void lunch_init() {
    orderList = (lunch *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(lunch));
    if (orderList == NULL) {printf("orderList allocation error!\n"); exit(1);}

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        orderList[i].ticketNum = -1;
        orderList[i].TID = -1;
        orderList[i].numServers = maxServer;
        orderList[i].takeALooksy = 0;
        sem_init(&(orderList[i].ready), 0, 1); // bin semaphore
        pthread_mutex_init(&(orderList[i].lock), NULL);
    }

        sem_init(&servers, 0, maxServer);
        sem_init(&empty, 0, MAX);
        sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
        pthread_mutex_init(&getTicketLock, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&waitTurnLock, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&waitCustomerLock, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&buffLock, NULL);
}

int lunch_get_ticket(lunch *cust) {
    printf("<%ld> enter <lunch_get_ticket>\n", pthread_self());

    //critical section begins
    pthread_mutex_lock(&getTicketLock);
    cust->ticketNum = ticketCounter++;
    printf("<%ld> get ticket <%d>\n", pthread_self(), cust->ticketNum);
    //critical section ends
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&getTicketLock);

    printf("<%ld> leave <lunch_get_ticket>\n", pthread_self());

    return cust->ticketNum;
}

void lunch_wait_turn(lunch *cust) { // customer gets stuck
    printf("<%ld> enter <lunch_wait_turn>\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_mutex_lock(&waitTurnLock);
    // wait for turn without busy waiting
    sem_wait(&servers);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&waitTurnLock);

    printf("<%ld> leave <lunch_wait_turn> after ticket <%d> served\n", pthread_self(), orderList[consumer - 1].ticketNum);  
}

void lunch_wait_customer(lunch *cust) {
    printf("<%ld> enter <lunch_wait_customer>\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cust->lock);
    if (currServer > 0) {
        nowServing++;
        currServer--;
        sem_wait(&(cust->ready));
        show_serving(nowServing);
        sem_post(&(servers)); // changed to servers from cust->ready
        printf("<%ld> after served ticket <%d>\n", pthread_self(), orderList[consumer].ticketNum);
    }
    // sem_wait(&(cust->ready));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(cust->lock));

    printf("<%ld> leave <lunch_wait_customer>\n", pthread_self());
    if (currServer > 0) consume();
}

void ordersUp(lunch customer){
    while(1) {
        sem_wait(&empty); // wait for an empty slot in the buffer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffLock); // only one can add to the buffer at a time
        orderList[producer] = customer;
        listCount++;
        producer = (producer + listCount) % MAX; // circ array
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffLock);
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}

void consume() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffLock);
    sem_wait(&full); // wait for something to consume
    listCount--;
    consumer = (consumer + listCount) % MAX;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffLock);
    sem_post(&empty);
}

void show_serving(int num) { printf("Serving <%d>\n", num); }

void *customer(void *threadId) {
    lunch *temp = (lunch *)threadId;
    temp->TID = (long int)pthread_self();
    temp->ticketNum = lunch_get_ticket(temp);
    temp->takeALooksy = mytime(1, (rand() % 10) + 1);
    printf("Sleeping Time: %d sec; Thread Id = %ld\n", temp->takeALooksy, pthread_self());
    ordersUp(*temp); // ??
    sleep(temp->takeALooksy);
    sem_post(&temp->ready);
    lunch_wait_turn(temp);
    return NULL;
}

void *server(void *threadId) {
    lunch *temp = (lunch *)threadId;
    sem_post(&servers);
    while (1) { // is this busy-waiting?
        lunch_wait_customer(temp);
        sleep(rand() % 5 + 1);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The mytime files were provided by my instructor.

mytime.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int mytime (int left, int right)
{
    int time = 0;
    time = left + rand()%(right - left);
    // printf("random time is %d sec\n", time);
    return time;
}
```

mytime.h:

```
int mytime (int left, int right);  // return a random time in the range of [left, right]. Default values are [left, right].
```

the entire error: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= fifo_max_prio)' failed.

Here is the project description:
You went to your favorite restaurant for lunch. While waiting, you observed their service process and thought you
could write a program to simulate it. The process you observed is like the following: a customer took a ticket first;
after a random while looking around, the customer was ready to order and the ticket number was displayed on a screen showing “Now Serving”. The order was processed by a new server being added (see Additional Requirements). Otherwise, the customer waits for the order to be processed. On the other hand, when there was no customer, a
server had to wait.

Note: in this project,
In this project, you will write code to simulate the above process using synchronization primitives of locks and
semaphores. They are available in pthread library in C. Use only locks and semaphores, i.e., no condition variables
or other synchronization primitives are allowed.

For the simulator to run, the total numbers of customers and the servers should be input from command line. If input is wrong, prompt should be given for try again with correct format. Sleep function for a random time should be used to simulate the time that a customer spending  looking around after getting the ticket. Sleep function for a random time should also be used to simulate the time that a server waiting to serve a current customer.

Hint: you could define a structure struct lunch, plus four functions described below. struct lunch should contain needed information for each client, such as TID, ticket # and be used in functions to pass
information. You can use a globe ticket # counter. Also, an order list should be used to store the submitted tickets.
In this way, the orders will be served first-come-first-serve. You can implement the list with your own preference. If
you implement using circular array, the buffer size can be fixed at 50 as the MAX.

(1) The initialization function for the struct lunch, invoked once, starting with there are no customers and no
servers.

```
void lunch_init(struct lunch *lunch)
```

(2) When a new customer arrives, he invokes the function

```
int lunch_get_ticket(struct lunch *lunch)
```

This function will return the customer's ticket number, which is also in the lunch variable as well, which is the smallest positive integer that has not been returned to any previous customer (1 for the first customer, 2 for the second, and so on). No two customers will receive the same ticket number. The queue can be within the struct lunch. After getting a ticket, the customer is free to look around
(simulate by random sleep). The following outputs are needed on this function.

```
<ThreadId Customer> enter <function name>
 <ThreadId Customer> get ticket <ticket number>
 <ThreadId Customer> leave <function name>
```

(3) Eventually, the customer will invoke the function

lunch_wait_turn(struct lunch *lunch)
This function must not return until there is an available server and the “Now Serving” screen shows a ticket number of the client. Once
lunch_wait_turn returns, the customer will be served by a server (no need to implement this mechanism).
The following outputs will be print out.

```
<ThreadId Customer> enter <function name> with <ticket number>
 <ThreadId Customer> leave <function name> after ticket < ticket number> served.
```

(4) When a new server arrives, he will invoke the function

```
lunch_wait_customer(struct lunch *lunch)
```

It must not return until there is a customer needing for service. The order list is helpful to assure clients are served first-come-first-serve. Once this function returns the server will service the customer (you do not need to implement that mechanism). The outputs
from the function are:

```
<ThreadId server > enter <function name>
<ThreadId server > after served ticket < ticket number>
<ThreadId server > leave <function name>
```

Requirements:
(i) Don't forget to write a function Show_serving(int number), which will cause number to be displayed in the “Now Serving” screen. Invoke this function as needed in your code. The output format: "Serving ".

(ii) Your solution must not use busy-waiting, e.g., waiting in a while loop.

Additional Requirements:
(a) Read from command line the # of servers and # clients. One server only serves once.In main program, don't forget join customers and servers.

(b) Use an array for each type of threads, also a loop and sleep with a random number. A client sleeps only after
getting the ticket. A server sleeps first before serving a client. Make sure that when using the random sleep duration, set a short sleep time. Before sleep, print out "Sleeping Time: X sec; Thread Id = ThreadId".

(c) You need to call the specific function mytime() (see files mytime.c, mytime.h) to obtain a random time to be the input to the sleep function. The makefile is provided.

(d) Feel free to use more functions wherever you see fit. The printouts should be used following the same format.

(e) Example of starting multiple threads are given in an early post, file name: PC-inputs-main.c

Comment: It is intentional that all your threads are sharing the same `lunch`?  Some of the members and some of the usage make me think not, but other details of the program make me think maybe so.

Comment: In some places you pass `lunch` objects by value and / or assign them using structure assignment.  These objects contain mutexes and semaphores, and although you can copy those in this way, it is not safe to try to use the resulting mutex and semaphore copies (though I'm not sure whether the program actually does that).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I appreciate you commenting! I will be completely honest, I was attempting to follow multiple examples on how to set up the program. That's probably where I got lost. Do you have any suggestions on what I could have done differently in that aspect? Even though I have turned in this assignment, I am dying to know how to correctly implement it.

Comment: Moreover, you have a whole lot of different mutexes and semaphores running around in this program.  That's not inherently wrong, but it's certainly suspicious that such a small program is using so many.

Comment: That sounds like "I don't know what I intended", which is hard for me to work with.  How about you start by editing in an explanation of what the program is supposed to do?  Include all details that influenced your design, please.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You hit the nail on the head. I was really struggling with this project and trying to understand how the built-in pthread and semaphore functions worked. I added the project description to my post if you have time to help me understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Preliminary

I don't know what, specifically, causes this:

> the entire error: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= fifo_max_prio)' failed.

I am inclined to guess that it is a manifestation of the undefined behavior of the program arising from data races and / or use of objects having indeterminate values, which I talk about below, but I have nothing more to say about this error message in particular.

#### Generalities

I can't say I think much of the specific language of the problem. It contains some confusing provisions, some of which seem positively inconsistent.  It contains some recommendations that seem a bit weird. And it contains some non-standard and even outright wrong wording.

Let's start here:

> the total numbers of customers and the servers should be input from command line. If input is wrong, prompt should be given for try again with correct format.

You seem to have partially addressed that, in that you look to the command-line arguments for the numbers of customers and servers, and you emit a diagnostic and terminate if the wrong number of command-line arguments is provided.  That's how I would interpret the requirements too, but I note that the instruction to *prompt* if the arguments are not correct could suggest that the program is expected to take interactive input instead.

In any case, what if the arguments do not correspond to integers?  Or what if they correspond to *non-positive* integers?  The `atoi()` function is simple to use, but it does not provide for any error checking.  I suggest [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) instead, which will allow you to verify that the whole argument is successfully parsed as an integer, combined with afterwards checking that the results are each greater than or equal to 1.

The next thing that catches my eye is this:

> Use only locks and semaphores, i.e., no condition variables or other synchronization primitives are allowed.

It's unclear what the assignment means by "locks".  Most likely it is *mutexes*, but pthreads also have read/write locks, which actually have "lock" in their name.  I presume that you will understand what the assignment means by virtue of being in the class and following the text and lectures.

The hint offered seems to contain a lot of *bona fide* requirements, and it's a bit inconsistent.  In particular, it says

> `struct lunch` should contain needed information for each client

but the fact that

> [there should be an] initialization function for the struct lunch, invoked once, [when] there are no customers and no servers.

seems to indicate that there is only one `struct lunch` per run of the program, shared among the threads, so that one object must contain information needed by *all* the customers.  And, presumably, by all the servers.

You seem to have provided for that.<sup>1</sup>  HOWEVER, because this object is accessed by multiple threads, and some of the accesses are writes, accesses to it occurring after the first additional thread is launched need to be synchronized -- for instance, performed only while holding locked a mutex designated for that purpose.  Also, it does not make sense to store anything in this object that is specific to a single thread, such as a thread ID, unless in a purely transitory manner.

You have provided a mutex inside of `struct lunch`, which I guess is intended for this purpose, but you never initialize or use it.

#### lunch_init()

Speaking of initialization, you have deviated from the specifications in the assignment with respect to the `lunch_init()` function.  It is supposed to take a pointer to a `struct lunch`, and initialize the structure to which that points.  Instead, yours takes no arguments, and initializes various global variables.  And you never initialize the `struct lunch` you create in `main()`.

Per the assignment, `lunch_init()` should have this signature:

```
void lunch_init(struct lunch *lunch);
```

Among the things it should do is:

```
    pthread_mutex_init(&lunch->lock);
```

And accordingly, you would use it from `main()` like so:

```
    // ...
    struct lunch lunch;
    lunch_init(&lunch);
```

When any thread accesses the members of the `struct lunch`, other than synchronization objects such as `lock`, that thread must first lock the mutex:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lunch->lock);
    // ... do stuff with lunch->any_member ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lunch->lock);
```

The threads should be sure not to hold the mutex locked longer than necessary, but what's necessary depends on what the threads are doing.

Now a few words about the other recommended functions:

#### lunch_get_ticket()

Your implementation for this looks mostly ok.  I note that you are using a mutex specific to protecting the lunch's latest ticket number instead of the mutex in the `struct lunch` itself.  You may do that if you like, and there are some advantages, but if you do, then I suggest moving the mutex into the `struct lunch`.  There *is* one problem here, however, which is that this function reads the lunch's `ticketNum` after releasing the mutex.  It must not do that.  Instead, copy the `ticketNum` to a local variable before releasing the mutex, then return the value of the local variable:

```
    // ...
    int ticketNum = cust->ticketNum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&getTicketLock);
    // ...
    return ticketNum;
```

#### lunch_wait_turn() and lunch_wait_customer()

These functions are supposed to work together to pair customers with servers. This is the tricky part of the exercise.  Your implementation has at least these issues:

- As `lunch_wait_turn()` is presently implemented, `waitTurnLock` serves no useful purpose.  It protects only a call to `sem_wait()`, which does not require such protection.
- There is no correlation between the "Now serving" ticket number that `lunch_wait_customer()` prints and the ticket number of the customer that is actually served (and this will be obvious in the output, because customer order will be randomized by their random waits, whereas the "Now serving" number will increase sequentially).

Unless you want to introduce a global variable for the purpose (don't), the customer and server threads have only the members of the `struct lunch` to use for communication, so that's where the ticket numbers will need to be exchanged.  The pattern probably needs to be along these lines:

- one customer at a time that is ready to be served gets access to record its ticket number in the `struct lunch` (see below).
- after it has done so, it grants access for one server to come in to get that (via the `servers` semaphore you're already using, for example), and blocks.  Note well that only one server may be allowed in at a time, lest multiple servers pick up the same ticket.
- when a server gains access, it reads the ticket number, then unblocks the waiting customer (probably via a different semaphore)
- the customer's release allows for the next customer to gain access

A simple(-ish) way to do that is

- for there to be a mutex dedicated to the customer side of the exchange (you have this already).  **Each customer** will lock this mutex before proceeding to ensure that only one is attempting to exchange a ticket number with a server at a time.
- **the customer** writes its ticket number into the lunch, then posts to a semaphore (i.e. your `servers`).
- **the customer** then waits for a different semaphore (this could be your `lunch.ready`, but that would be a completely different use than it now serves).
- When it proceeds, **the customer** unlocks the mutex, allowing the next customer in.  Meanwhile,
- **The servers** each arrive and wait on the semaphore gating their access.
- When one gets through, **that server** reads the recorded ticket number, prints the appropriate "Now serving" message, and posts to the semaphore allowing the customer to proceed.

Note, however, that that does not necessarily provide first-come, first-served semantics, because pthreads mutexes do not, generally, guarantee FIFO ordering.  That's described in the assignment, but it's not clear to me whether it's an actual requirement.  If it *is* a requirement, then that's unfortunate, because there's no good way to implement it without either busy-waiting or condition variables, neither of which is allowed to you.  But a *bad* way might involve a circular queue of semaphores.  The assignment suggests that 50 slots would be enough.  A thread would enqueue itself by waiting on the next available semaphore in the queue, and a thread would dequeue a waiting thread by posting to the first in-use semaphore in the queue.

#### Summary

Your code has some issues, but it's on the right track.  Do think about what various variables and function parameters represent and assign them names reflecting that.  You might be surprised how much that helps keep track of what's going on.  Also, pay attention to proper synchronization, and get the basics working before you embellish (such as with `ordersUp()` and `consume()`).

I have intentionally avoided writing much code for you, as working things out for yourself is where you will gain most of the benefit of this exercise, but I think and hope that these remarks will get you going in the right direction.

---

<sup>1</sup>Except that `struct LUNCH` is not the same as `struct lunch`, with or without the `typedef`.  I recommend ignoring the existence of the `typedef` keyword to the greatest extent possible, at least until you have more experience.  It is occasionally convenient, but never required, and IMO, it gets way overused.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth reply! I cannot begin to explain how appreciative I am! I will put your words into practice now that I have a better understanding! Thank you again!